# Logstash twitter input yields no output

Tags: twitter, logstash

I am trying to track tweets about our new app.  I am not doing any filtering on the tweets as of now.

Here is my input and output configs that relate to twitter

```
input {
    twitter {
            consumer_key => "xxx"
            consumer_secret => "xxx"
            oauth_token => "xxx-xxx"
            oauth_token_secret => "xxx"
            keywords => ["keyword1", "keyword2", "keyword3", "keyword4"]
            full_tweet => true
            type => "tweet"
    }

}

output {
    if [type] == "error_log" {
            elasticsearch {
                    host => localhost
                    index => "error_logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            }
    }
    else if [type] == "tweet"{
            elasticsearch {
                    host => localhost
                    index => "tweets-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            }
    }
    else {
            elasticsearch {
            host => localhost
            }
    }

}
```

I checked all my keys/tokens from my twitter dev console and they are all correct.

I am confused because there are no logs pertaining to twitter in the  3 log locations logstash writes to:

- /var/log/logstash/logstash.err
- /var/log/logstash/logstash.log
- /var/log/logstash/logstash.stdout

Can anyone lend any insight as to what might be going wrong?

I am using logstash version 1.5.0.rc2 and java version 1.8.0_45.

Comment: If you haven't already tried it, running the Logstash agent with `-v` should yield more debug logging.

Comment: I figured it out... the twitter input just monitors *new* tweets, not old tweets that have already been made...  Everything works fine for new tweets.  This was not mentioned in the docs.  gaaah